# Notification scheduling

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an android app which is about meal subsciption.
I update the entire menu(breakfast, lunch , dinner) for each day in the morning( I am using firebase).
Now i want to send scheduled notification to users that is, i want to notify a user at 1pm that this is the coming menu for the lunch similarly i want to notify the user at around 8pm that this is the coming menu of dinner.
What should i use to get this scheduled notification?

I had an idea in mind that when i update the database in the morning. I will send a data payload with the required scheduling time using cloud messanging and schedule the notification on the device itself.
Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work, I recommend using Worker to schedule notification and take into account receiving notifications while the app is in the background, because your app should have that feature I guess.

Comment: Thanks i'll give it a try